# What's the difference between these functions

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7

What's the difference between these functions

1. `create_task` and `call_soon`
2. `call_soon_threadsafe` and `run_coroutine_threadsafe`

### create_task vs call_soon

these two functions schedule the execution of a Coroutines, not thread-safe.
`create_task` returns a `Task` object, and `call_soon` returns `Handle` object, but is there any difference other than this, especially in usage?

### call_soon_threadsafe vs run_coroutine_threadsafe

these two functions are meant to be called from a different OS thread than the one where the event loop is running. And in most cases, I can use any of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `create_task` vs `call_soon` - these two functions schedule the execution of a Coroutines

No, only `create_task` schedules the execution of a coroutine (async function). `call_soon` schedules the one-shot execution of an ordinary function.

So, if you have a coroutine `x` defined with `async def` that you want executed "in the background", you call `asyncio.create_task(x())`. If you have a function `f` defined with `def` that you want executed as soon as the event loop is next idle, you call `loop.call_soon(f)`.

The same difference in usage applies to `run_coroutine_threadsafe` and `call_soon_threadsafe`, which allow submitting work to a running event loop from a different thread.

Comment: do coroutines run at same time as the one-shot callbacks ? or their execution is interleaved ?

Comment: @Claudiu the event loop is single threaded and, the code being run by the event loop can only be preempted at "await" calls. Thus coroutines passed to create_task/run_coroutine_threadsafe will interleave, but only at those points of execution. On the other hand, call_soon and call_soon_threadsafe receive plain functions, they execute completely without interruption. Also, as the doc states, execution of call_soon* happens only once the event loop is idle ( all coroutines are blocked waiting for something )